# What is the gcc ARM equivalent to this x64 assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

This is the X64 code (I don't know much about assembly, and this code can be compiled by visual studio, don't know which format it is):

```
.code
extern mProcs:QWORD

myfunc proc
jmp mProcs[1*8]   
myfunc endp
```

The mProcs is an array defined in C code, and the function myfunc simply jmp to the second element in the array. If viewed from C, it is jumping to *(mProcs+1) (1*8 because in x64 a pointer is 8 bytes).

In GCC ARM version, I tried to do this:

```
.extern mProcs
.global myfunc
myfunc:
    b mProcs+4
```

(here mProcs+4 because a pointer is 4 bytes)

But this code seems no working. In C does it means jump to *(mProcs+1) or jump to mProcs+1?
How can I make it *(mProcs+1)?

============================================================================

After discussion in the comments with Michael, I understood that I need to do the calculation on the register and then use the bx instruction to jump to the target function.

However, the problem comes here. 
Since I'm implementing a thunk (I'm intercepting the function call and do something in the middle), I have no idea how the target routine uses the register.

**1.** I need to keep the callee save registers before I jmp to the target, else the target function will be preserving the wrong value.

**2.** I need to keep the argument registers intact before I perform a jump, so that the target function will have the correct arguments.
3. The above 2 points means I can only use caller save but non-argument registers.

r0-r3 is the argument register, and r4-r12 are callee save register, r13 onwards are special registers.

Which means none of the registers can be used without restoring the value.

If the bx instruction can only operate on a register, then there is no chance I can restore that register even if that register is temporally saved on the stack.

Any solutions? Or just arm binaries can't be hooked.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `ldr r0,=myfunc` / `ldr r0,[r0,#4]` / `bx r0` ?  (note that you might have to use some other register than `r0`)

Comment: @Michael not quite clear to me, you don't even have mProcs in the code, can I just do "b [mProcs, #4]"?

Comment: Oops. `myfunc` was supposed to be `mProcs` in my example. And no, you can't do `b [mProcs, #4]`, because ARM is load/store-based architecture, so most instructions except `ldr/str` can't have memory operands.

Comment: @Michael Cool, understood your code, I wonder which register can I use? I'm making a thunk in the assembly which simply jump to the target function. As I do some googling the r0-r3 may be the argument registers, which I can not use. The other core registers are callee save register and I can not overwrite either, or do I need to swap on the stack?

Comment: @Michael After I did some readings, I think r4 can not be used for this purpose, since the subroutines are supposed to restore the content of r4-r12 after execution. But since my assembly code here is a thunk, what it does is jumping to the subroutine. If I jump after modifying any of r4-r12, the subroutine will be saving and restoring the wrong value.

Comment: I wonder how this is possible without ruining the registers. Even I push the register to stack, if I jump to another address, there is no chance for me to do a pop.

Comment: I don't know how it would look for ARM, but one way to work around this is to set up the target as a fake return address on the stack, and "return" to it. Because you're storing it on the stack, you can restore any damaged registers before returning.

Comment: In fact, it looks like storing the target address in r15 (after restoring any other registers you touched) might be sufficient.

Comment: @Useless It is not that easy to set r15 when everything but the stack is clean. Coz stm operations will sort the register from low to high. But the first value pushed into the stack is definitely not the target address.

Comment: @scott if you can show some link or document in an answer I'll accept your answer. (I already see some quite ambiguous docs says r12 is used inter procedure, but none of those clearly say that it does not need to be preserved)

Comment: The [ARM EABI Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/index.html) (PDF) allows a thunk (often called a "veneer") to use/change `r12`. No value is passed in in `r12` and the callee is not required to preserve it.  The register conventions are in section 5.1.1.  [I don't think you can accept a comment as an answer, but you can increment it.]

Comment: @scott OK, I find this in the PDF you provide, "Clarified when linking may insert veneers that corrupt r12 and the condition codes". I have used r12 in my code, and the program runs normally. If you would put it in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Min Lin:  you're allowed to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) -- that seems most appropriate since it's a combination of the comments and you can easily show the working, tested code.

One further comment:  it would be be good to improve the title (if possible) because "What is the gcc ARM equivalent to this x64 assembly" doesn't mention thunks/wrapping or tables of function pointers.